Can one solve this complex linear equation
Suppose the equations are as follows:
$$\text{tr}\{AH\}= c$$
where $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $A$ is a symmetric matrix in $M_{N}(\mathbb{R})$ are both known and $H$ is a Hermitian matrix which looks like:
$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & e^{i\phi_{12}} & e^{i\phi_{13}} & \cdots & e^{i\phi_{1N}}\\
e^{-i\phi_{12}} & 1 & e^{i\phi_{23}} & \cdots & e^{i\phi_{2N}} \\
e^{-i\phi_{13}} & e^{-i\phi_{23}} & 1 & \cdots & e^{i\phi_{3N}} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
e^{-i\phi_{1N}} & e^{-i\phi_{2N}} & e^{-i\phi_{3N}} & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and finally:
$$\phi_{ij} + \phi_{jk} = \phi_{ik} \ \ \ \forall \ \ i,j < k \ \ \text{where} \ \ i,j,k \in I_N = {1,...,N}$$
Find is $H$ in terms of $A$ and $C$?

My personal idea to start with is to introduce an inner product over $M_{N}(\mathbb{C})$ by:
$$\langle A , B \rangle = \text{tr}\{A^{\dagger} B\} \ \ \ \ \forall \ \ A,B \in M_{N}(\mathbb{C})$$
Given this one can argue that $\langle A , B \rangle = \text{tr}\{ A^{\dagger} H\} = \text{tr}\{ A H\}$ which results in:
$$H = \frac{c}{N} A^{-1} + B \ \ \ \text{where} \ \ \ \ \text{tr}\{AB\} = 0$$
meaning that $B \  \text{is perpendicular to} \ A$.
Using Hermiticity of $H$:
$$B-B^{\dagger} = A^{-1} \frac{\left(c^* - c \right)}{N}= -\frac{2\text{Im} \{c\}}{N} A^{-1} $$
Knowing that $\text{Im} \ {c} \neq 0$ this expression means that the anti-Hermitian part of $B$ is nonzero.
Writing $B = \frac{1}{2}\left( B + B^{\dagger}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( B - B^{\dagger} \right)$ there remains finding the Hermitian part of $B : \ \ \frac{1}{2} \left( B + B^{\dagger} \right)$.
Also by a simple calculation one can reduce the number of independent phases to $N-1$ which can be assumed to leave only $(e^{\phi_{12}},...,e^{\phi_{1N}})$ as independent components of $H$
Honestly, I don't know how to use the $H$ matrix form even further to fix $B$.
Any other approach to a solution is welcome.
